# Changing a visa I have already applied for to emergency

Tags: visas, usa

Is it possible for me to get an emergency visa to the USA from Canada, which I already scheduled for a later time? I need to go to a funeral.

Comment: What's your nationality?

Comment: @gparyani from "I already scheduled for a later time," it's probably safe to assume that Lyd requires a visa to enter the US.  But, to be thorough, Lyd, we should make sure that you know that a visa is not required for most Canadian citizens or for those who travel under the Visa Waiver Program (which is limited to citizens of certain countries who visit for business or pleasure for no more than 90 days).

Comment: I wouldn't waste time waiting for answers from the Internet - call the embassy and ask them.

Comment: OP has not returned to clarify questions, putting on hold.